# Kubernetes Docker Hub Private

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerhub

I am using Minikube to setup a k8s environment for later production but I can't figure out how to pull private container from Docker Hub in my service definition.

I added

```
imagePullSecrets:
    - name: dockerregistrykey
```

to the service definition `spec.template.spec` and the `dockerregistrykey` to the secrets.

But I am still getting this error

```
Failed to pull image "keyshake/transaction_service:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for keyshake/transaction_service, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the use of the pullSecret at container level:

```
...
spec:
  containers:
    - name: my_container
      image: your_image
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: dockerregistrykey
```